# Is there a name for this idiom that computes a new result based on a previous value and result?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

Is there a standard name for this "Deriver" idiom (written in Typescript, but not Typescript-specific):

```js
type Derivation<T, R> = { value: T, result: R };
type Deriver<T, R> = (
    previous: Derivation<T, R> | undefined,
    value: T
) => R;
```

where a `deriver` is a function that computes a new value `R` using the previous value/result as a hint to potentially optimize the new computation?

Here's an example of such a function:

```js
function complexCalculation(a: number, b: number): number {
    // assume that this function is expensive
    return a + b;
}

function calcDeriver(
    previous: Derivation<number[], number> | undefined,
    value: number[]
): number {
    if (previous) {
        if (previous.value === value) {
            return previous.result;
        }
        let samePrefix = true;
        if (previous.value.length < value.length) {
            for (let i = 0; i < previous.value.length; i++) {
                if (previous.value[i] !== value[i]) {
                    samePrefix = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (samePrefix) {
            return value
                .slice(previous.value.length)
                .reduce(complexCalculation, previous.result);
        }
    }

    return value.reduce(complexCalculation, 0);
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how it's used / implemented?

Comment: Sure - added one to the description.

Comment: Imperative programming? Dynamic programming? Memoisation?

Comment: How are you calling `calcDeriver`? This function doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was this was a form of [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) with only a single memoized result. However, if that's was the case, you'd simply return `previous.result` if `samePrefix` was found.

Instead it looks like what you're doing is creating a kind of [Reduce / Fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) function that is capable of picking up where it left off from a previous state.

There are many different names for this pattern, so its up to you to determine what you think best fits in your case. Here are some suggestions:

- `Reduction` / `Reducer`
- `FoldResult` / `Folder`
- `Aggregation` / `Aggregator`

Comment: the pattern that is really being described here happens at .reduce(complexCalculation, previous.result), +1 to this answer